# Cannot deploy more than one application to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I have developed two Windows Phone applications and would like to deploy them on a physical device for a demo. I can deploy and run each of them separately on a physical device, but I cannot deploy both of applications at the same time. Are there any restrictions on number of applications deployed?

Observable behaviour:

1. Open first project in VS, Rebuild, Select "Windows Phone 7 Device", Deploy.
2. Application appears in the phone. Fully functional.
3. Open second project in VS, Rebuild, Select "Windows Phone 7 Device", Deploy.
4. During the deploy process the first application disappears and the second one appears in a few seconds.
5. Second application is fully functional.

More information:

- applications are developed and deployed through VS2010 Ultimate SP1;
- physical device: Samsung Omnia 7;
- phone is unlocked;
- applications have different names (xap file name and title);
- ProjectGuids are different in csproj files.

Has someone encountered similar issues?

Comment: I found another thread "[Deploy more than one WP7 App with same Visual Studio Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300565/deploy-more-than-one-wp7-app-with-same-visual-studio-solution)" about similar issue. It was not my case, but it might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that the value for the `ProductId` attribute in the `App` element of the WMAppManifest.xml file is different in each application. You can generate a new GUID from the **Tools** menu in Visual Studio if necessary.

Comment: Derek, you are right. I had the same ProductID in both manifest files. I did not spot it even comparing those files. My mistake.
Thank you for such fast reply!

Comment: Regarding generation of new guids. In VS I use a "nguid" snippet. Just type "nguid" -> press Tab to choose the format -> press Tab to confirm.